# Transport gets stuck

Tags: anylogic

I'm implementing a model in which many transport (Transport fleet, Material Handling library) move in the same network.

I've got some limited access paths ( limited to 1 transport).

The intersection between two or more path are nodes; in this way if a path is already occupied it will stay in the node until the path is free again.

The model seems to run until some transport get stuck (see screenshot).

At the moment Transport are able to resolve collision, but if the Resolve collision parameter is false  then when transports get stuck a collision is detected.

I think transport cannot choose who can be the first to can cross the path (my thought, any suggestion is appreciated).

It is not a constant problem, it can happen at different times of the one year simulation or not happen at all.

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks

[Transport stuck image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dHX6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the underlying algorithms cannot possibly work for any situation or foresee any eventuality.

Either you use the build-in resolution or you have to apply custom intelligence, route-finding and decision-making, which is possible but not trivial :)